Fetch the title of a web page using URL in javascript
How to fetch any page title using URL in javascript front end. But I don not want to load the full page in response this method takes a lot of time to find result. Is there any quick way to achieve this goal?
const proxyUrl = 'https://api.allorigins.win/get?url='+encodeURIComponent(url);
const response = await fetch(proxyUrl);
const data = await response.json();
const html = data.contents;
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
const pageTitle = doc.querySelector('title').textContent;


its fixed now there was a single quote error in the code.

How do you want to gather the title (which is part of the markup) without loading the markup?

I think you will need to download the whole page, although you may get away with using a RegExp rather than DOMParser?

@NicoHaase yes if we load the full HTML into DOMparser then, depending upon the page size this takes 10-20 seconds to fetch the result.

You could potentially try a HEAD request (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30891843/519413), but for this to work it would depend on how the API response is formed.

@evolutionxbox see that method will take too much time. I getting the result with this function. but its not fast enough.

You don't really have much of an alternative, if you're restricted to client-side code. The content of the response is not available until the request is finalised, and that only occurs when all content has been retrieved. You cannot retrieve only a portion of the page in the response. The better approach would be to make the request server side yourself, then parse the response there before handing just the required information back to your client code.

What part takes 20+ seconds? What about using data.contents.match(/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/)?

@evolutionxbox correct.

You might want to read his question again XD

A HEAD request will be faster, but since it doesn't have a body I don't see how you'd be able to get the title from such a request

I would use /<title>(.+?)<\/title>/i in case they have upper case TITLE, and possibly even do that on the data instead of the parsed JSON data.content

Does this answer your question? Can Ajax return data line by line as received from the server?

for parsing HTML with regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454
